# Eclipse Android X86 Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: android

Running Eclipse Build id: 20110615-0604

Android SDK & AVD Manager (setup in eclipse)

Android X86 2.3-RC1.eeepc.iso

Oracle VM VirtualBox Version 4.1.2.r73507 (installed and running android)

In the VM using Alt F1 and the command netcfg produces:

```
Android root@eeepc:/ # netcfg
lo UP 127.0.0.1  255.0.0.0  0x00000049
```

The path for Android is set in eclipse to C:\android\android-sdk

In the tools directory I use the command 'adb kill-server'
I then use `'adb connect 127.0.0.1'` which produces:

```
unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:5555
```

I have a virtual device setup already in Eclipse using the AVD manager and this works perfectly - though very slowly, hence the need to use X86.

When the working emulator is running the command `'adb devices'` produces:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 (the slow emulator)
```

When the slow emulator is running and I then use the command `'adk kill-server'` and use the command `'adb connect 127.0.0.1'` it produces:

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 127.0.0.1
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 127.0.0.1:5555
```

So then I go back to:

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb connect 127.0.0.1
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
connected to 127.0.0.1:5555

C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
127.0.0.1:5555  device
```

But the new X86 device, presumably at `127.0.0.1:5555` doesn't appear in the `AVD manager`. Should it? I'm stumped.

I've googled everywhere so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How is the network interface configured in Virtual Box for the android x86 VM? 127.0.0.1 will not be accessible from the host machine, you will need to use NAT or Bridge mode on network interface to be able to setup ADB connection from the host to the guest VM.

Comment: I think this may help [Debuging using Virtual machine like VMWare/VirtualBox?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648009/debuging-using-virtual-machine-like-vmware-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

Hello James, 
            I tried a similar set up and I got the same error as you. I eventually gave up using virtualbox. After struggling for two days I switched to using vmware and I had to use a different image. 
I used the following image: http://android-x86.googlecode.com/files/android-x86-2.2-r2-eeepc.iso
and for the vmware set up I followed this tutorial: http://vmetc.com/2010/12/27/install-androidx86-in-a-vmware-workstation-vm/

Do not skip over the part that says to edit the virtual machines configuration file. 
I hope this helps.

You might also want to consider using the android image provided by http://www.vmlite.com/ it worked right away for me and I connected using "adb connect 127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of "unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:5555". I then found here:

http://www.android-x86.org/documents/debug-howto

...

2.using adb with a NAT'ed VM

•The steps above work nicely if you have a VM which is set up to use Bridged or Host-Only adapters
•However, if you have a NAT'ed VM you cannot connect to the VM IP from the host
•You will need to set up port forwarding for a host port to be forwarded to the VM port 5555 (which is adb)
VBoxManage modifyvm  --natpf1 adb,tcp,*,,*,5555
Example from one machine:
VBoxManage modifyvm froyo --natpf1 adb,tcp,*,5555,*,5555
•Once this is done, you should see the local port (i.e. 5555 in this case) bound on the host via netstat -a
•You can now connect to the VM by adb localhost:5555

That solved the problem for me. Good luck!