# Any way to speed up the Debugging of Android Application?

Tags: android, debugging

I'm building the android application but I'm fed up while I'm designing my app every time I change even font size I will have to wait for re-installation is there any way to speed up this designing way?
and also
if I change the code every time I'll have to debug is there any way to speed up this task too?

My main question is if I navigated to 10 Activity and the changes are in 11
then I'll have to re-navigate every time I would be hectic. I can not move directly to the 11th activity coz I need some values from the previous activity and one more thing

```
something like on-web page we do just refresh that particular page and see changes
```

##Note: This question will help you a lot with this problem [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648009/debuging-using-virtual-machine-like-vmware-virtualbox)

Comment: What dou you mean by reinstallation? Restarting the emulator or uploading the edited .apk?

Comment: You can use debuggers...

Comment: @package : re-installation mean uploading edited apk and its installation not restarting emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have felt that debugging on device directly is faster than using emulators. Also, if you're working in windows, its a little slower than Linux and MacOS. You can try those platforms too

Comment: sorry in company only xp is installed

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it is inevitable that you have to re-install the apk to test some changes. In order to speed this up, the only way will be to try to fine tune your system, so that it runs faster.

For testing a simple change, like a new font size, you don't have to reinstall the apk however. You can visualize the changes inside Eclipse or use a tool like [DroidDraw](http://droiddraw.org/).

Answer (score 1):

kishu27 is correct by saying that debugging on a device is *far* quicker than using the emulator. If you don't have a device available, you can keep the emulator open between runs, so you don't have to wait for it to initialize each time (which really is painfully slow).

Another tip - if you have a lot of resources in the project that results in a large APK file, you could take out all the unnecessary ones while you're debugging a particular part of the application. This can speed up the installation process if the APK becomes a fair bit smaller. (This comes from experience when I was writing an app that had many sample videos in for testing - cutting out all but one and using that one wherever possible when it didn't matter *what* video was there meant the APK was far smaller and vastly sped up installation time.)

Comment: my apk size is only 500kb so no much resource
and i never close my emulator if once started 
and also i do have device but it's still a little slower

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you're likely stuck with the speed you're currently getting then - when I was researching debugging Android both for SDK and NDK, I didn't come across any tips for speeding up that part of the process. If you feel the device is slow you could always try asking your company if you could get a better/faster phone to test on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a faster way though, first step run the debugger in Android Studio. The first thing you notice is debugger breakpoints might slow debugging dramatically(something like that). Then click on this ...

[image]

[image]
Here you can see all the breakpoints you have in your project.

[image]

You can remove debug points left in your project in the bottom box.
This boosted my debug process in any device this is the best solution.