# Android Emulator in Eclipse doesnt start

Tags: android, emulation

I have an problem with eclipse juno when launching my app into a emulator. The problem have started recently.

I made a search on web for the problem . but I didnt get solution.

So, emulator starts but doesnt pass the "andorid" text on screen and app never been started.

I deleted all device and created new ones. But problem still exists.
what should I do?

Comment: did you try rebooting your computer, and also try running eclipse as administrator if your using windows, maybe

Comment: ADT version? you must start it with intel x86

Comment: I am trying your advice, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do what was mentioned by Hi-Tech Kit Kat. Also if you check the box "Use Host GPU" it will considerably speed up start time as it uses you computers assets for the graphics. A lot of times the emulator works, it's just that you run out of patience.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Emulators take to on Startup say around even 5 mins

1. You can have a try by Starting it lower version of android say to your mintargetsdk version
2. If you have Intel x86 installed with android Platform you must use it.
3. I recommend you to follow this Question's Answer to have a better setup
   [Slow Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

and also for better performance than any emulator and like real device I would recommend to use Android x86 using Virtual Box

[Debuging using Virtual machine like VMWare/VirtualBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648009/debuging-using-virtual-machine-like-vmware-virtualbox)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Eclipse on a laptop, you can change the Power Options. I have found that this is very helpful, instead of having to install/uninstall some items.

Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Select "High Performance"

This helped my emulator start up much quicker than previously; there is minimal lag.

I hope this helps.