# android adb devices return empty in VM

Tags: android, bluestacks

I can able to automate some test cases in Bluestack emulator in my local environment using appium, but when I do the same setup and execute the test case in AWS workspace VM, Appium returns '0 devices attached' in the console.

I compared my local adm setup and VM. Both are same.
I tried(adb kill-server, adb start-server, adb devices) in command line in VM. it returns empty.

Emulator I used: Bluestacks

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648009/debugging-using-a-virtual-machine-like-vmware-virtualbox

Comment: I tried all, but no luck